# How to stop wrapping lines in Stata main window?

Tags: stata

I work in Stata in window and lines are automatically being wrapped, which outputs very ugly. Is there any way to change it (i.e. don't wrap lines at all)?

Comment: `set linesize 255` may help in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the output is sensitive to the window size. You can adjust the entire window or make the variable and command list smaller to help.

Are you copy and pasting out? If so, it is probably better to generate the output in some other way that doesn't require that.